# Graphing frequency of categorical variable by month in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, frequency

Here is an example of the data I'm working with:

```
   SMUGGLING VIOLENCE AUXILIARY      Month
        Yes       No        No 2017-07-01
        Yes       No       Yes 2017-03-01
        Yes       No        No 2017-05-01
        Yes       No        No 2017-02-01
        Yes     <NA>      <NA> 2016-02-01
```

I am trying to graph the frequency of Smuggling=="Yes" over time (by month, 2016-2017). So I would just like the frequency of SMUGGLING on the y-axis (which I already subsetted to take out the No's), with the time by month on the x-axis.

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(data = smugglingyes,
   aes(Month, SMUGGLING)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = sum, 
           geom = "line") +
  scale_x_date(date_labels="%Y-%m", date_breaks = "1 month")
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBFfB.jpg) is just a rough example of the output I'm getting from ggplot2 (it will be cleaned up once I figure out the right way to graph this).

I'm very confused on if this is displaying the counts, as that's what I thought the `stat_summary` part of the code would do, but the "Yes" on the y-axis is misleading me and there aren't any numbers on the y-axis. Any idea how to fix this graph?

Answer (score 1):

Why not aggregate it before passing to ggplot? E.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(Smuggling = "Yes", 
                 Violence = "No",
                 Auxiliary = c("No", "Yes", "No", "No", NA),
                 Month = c("2017-07-01", "2017-03-01", "2017-05-01", "2017-02-01", "2016-02-01"))

df %>% 
  mutate(Month = lubridate::ymd(Month)) %>% 
  count(Month) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = n)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: You can replace `group_by(Month) %>% summarise(cnt = n())` with `count(Month)`

Comment: Thanks @bouncyball, not the first time I forgot this :)

Comment: That worked, thanks @erocoar and @bouncyball! Now I have this [this](https://imgur.com/hMO5m3t), so that is the count of smuggling per month, correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)